# DOMDocument load php file?

Tags: php, domdocument

I have a php file, with xml headers, that i wish my script to load.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load( 'xmlscript.php' );
```

Will not work, only files with *.xml. How can i make it load the file, like it is a xml file?

Since it's the data from db, that it shows in xml format, the file is in .php.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to get the output from the PHP file, and parse that.

```
ob_start();
include 'xmlscript.php';
$result = ob_get_clean();

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc -> loadXml($result);
```

Something like that may help.

Comment: ob_end_clean() is also needed to flush the buffer. After $result is defined

Comment: I get ErrorException [ Warning ]: DOMDocument::load() [<a href='domdocument.load'>domdocument.load</a>]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity

Comment: How? I already have this: header("Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8"); at the top of the xmlscript.php

Comment: I think it has problems with the " and '

Comment: Did not do any difference. >.<

Comment: After my script on xmlscript.php has loaded its data from the database im outputting it with echo. And i did echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>'; here too.

Comment: No Im not outputting any path ? thats the thing

Comment: http://pastebin.com/xiM24upZ is all it outputs. I dont know why its there hope you can help me out